# Syntax error when start $ heroku open

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I am new to Heroku and I am trying to deploy my first app onto Heroku.
I followed instruction, which were:

1. **git init**, **add** and **commit** my app's source code.
2. **heroku create** to create Heroku remote repo for my app.
3. **git push heroku master** to push my app's source code to heroku
4. **heroku open**

Problem happened when I tried to run **heroku open**, which was:

```
$ heroku open
(node:6192) SyntaxError Plugin: 
heroku:C:\Users\hauph\AppData\Local\heroku\conf                                                                                    
ig.json: Unexpected string in JSON at position 72 module: 
@oclif/config@1.6.33
task: runHook prerun
plugin: heroku
root: C:\Program Files\heroku\client
See more details with DEBUG=*
```

[Image taken from that error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBdJz.png)

I checked file config.json at the direction as addressed above, and it was:

```
{
  "schema": 1,
  "install": "554c101b-d4de-496c-9768-710142ebfb20"
}
 "skipAnalytics": false
}
```

So what did I do wrong here?

I would be grateful for any help.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I just tried deleting the file and running login again, it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `config.json` contains invalid JSON (note the two closing brackets). Reinstall the Heroku CLI, and you should be in good shape.

Comment: I reinstalled the whole heroku and it works! Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.  Not sure why it ends up corrupted, but the config.json should look like the following (get rid of the curly brace before skipAnalytics):

```
{
  "schema": 1,
  "install": "3265b92a-27f4-4adb-9c07-75d9213f0000",
  "skipAnalytics": false
}
```

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the Heroku CLI? Because I did it and it solved my problem, like @AdamMcrea 's answer

Answer (score 1):

I tried reinstalling but didn't work, just add curly braces in the config.json file.

```
{
    
}
```

Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I tried to build on `heroku` as like below

```
(node:1179857) SyntaxError Plugin: heroku: /home/{...}/.local/share/heroku/config.json: Unexpected end of JSON input
module: @oclif/config@1.18.3
task: runHook prerun
plugin: heroku
root: /snap/heroku/4085
See more details with DEBUG=*
set git remote heroku to https://git.heroku.com/{...}.git
```

So I opened the `config.json` file from this path `/home/{...}/.local/share/heroku/config.json` and added blank curly braces

```
{

}
```

Then I run the command `heroku git:remote -a {your project name}` to set `heroku git remote`

Finally checked the `config.json` file and added valid `json` value automatically like this screenshot:

```
{
  "schema": 1,
  "install": "19975845-fr45-hfgt6-iu78-c27hgy243c46d",
  "skipAnalytics": false
}
```

Finally `set remote` successfully. I hope it will make developers easier to deploy on `heroku` if this type of error comes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    USAGE
  $ heroku apps:open [PATH]

OPTIONS
  -a, --app=app        (required) app to run command against
  -r, --remote=remote  git remote of app to use

EXAMPLES
  $ heroku open -a myapp
  # opens https://myapp.herokuapp.com

  $ heroku open -a myapp /foo
  # opens https://myapp.herokuapp.com/foo
```

Please visit heroku cli commands documentation here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands