# Error when deploying the project to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I´m trying to deploy my project to Heroku (I´m doing the Python CrashCourse project). But when I enter the command: heroku ps

```
Warning: heroku update available from 7.46.2 to 7.47.0.
(node:16428) SyntaxError Plugin: heroku: C:\Users\vlado\AppData\Local\heroku\config.json: Unexpected string in JSON at position 72
module: @oclif/config@1.13.2
task: runHook prerun
plugin: heroku
root: H:\Program Files H\heroku\client
See more details with DEBUG=*
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 550h 0m (100%)
Free dyno usage for this app: 0h 0m (0%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

=== web (Free): gunicorn learning_log.wsgi --log-file - (1)
web.1: **crashed** 2020/10/29 18:25:25 +0100 (~ 7m ago)
```

The crash in bold should not be there. Probably also in the first lines the SyntaxError Plugin and Unexpected string in JSON...

Then when I enter Heroku open, my project won´t load and shows an error.

Could you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here you should find a similar question and answers: 
[Syntax error when start $ heroku open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51678095/syntax-error-when-start-heroku-open)

If that doesn't help post the log and json file in question

Comment: I reinstalled Heroku and now I don´t have the json error, but I still cannot run my project. It shows me the Application error.

This is what shows me after I enter command heroku ps. No json error anymore
Warning: heroku update available from 7.46.2 to 7.47.0.
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 550h 0m (100%)
Free dyno usage for this app: 0h 0m (0%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
=== web (Free): gunicorn learning_log.wsgi --log-file - (1)
web.1: crashed 2020/10/29 19:41:51 +0100 (~ 1h ago)

Comment: do you have gunicorn in your requirements.txt? + please post the log

Comment: Hm, there was a command pip freeze > requirements.txt to the virtual environment but I didn´t do this because I couldn´t. It shows me this error: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vlado\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\VLAD-všetko\Programovanie\Python\\PYTHON PROJECTS\Web Application\learning_log\ll_env\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli.main'

Comment: How can I generate the log, please?